# How to use SQLite ID for each table cell row

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a straight-forward question. I'm wondering how to use my "storeID" statement:

```
int storeID = sqlite_column_int(statement, 0)
```

in my SQLite query:...."StoreID=%d".

I need to be able to select a table cell row based on the SQLite ID #. I tried the method below but it doesn't recognize the storeID from the statement (probably because the compiler reads top-bottom.

```
- (void)retrieveData;
{
{


NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT StoreID, StoreName, StoreAddr, StoreHost, StorePort, StoreUser, StorePass, StoreDB FROM storelist WHERE StoreID=%d", storeID];
sqlite3_stmt* statement;
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(companyDB, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
if (SQLITE_OK == result) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        int storeID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSString *address = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        NSString *host = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
        NSString *port = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
        NSString *user = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
        NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
        NSString *db = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];

        NSLog(@"StoreID= %i\tStoreName= %@\tStoreAddress= %@\tStoreHost= %@\tStorePort= %@\tStoreUser= %@\tStorePass= %@",storeID,name,address,host,port, user, pass);


        Company *company = [[Company alloc]init];

        [company setStoreID:storeID];
        [company setName:name];
        [company setAddress:address];
        [company setHost:host];
        [company setPort:port];
        [company setUser:user];
        [company setPass:pass];
```

Comment: Which line is the problem? Does your `Company` class have a `storeID:` property? What's its type?

Comment: Yes, my Company class has a storeID property. The problem is on my *query line. StoreID=%d, storeID   <--- that storeID doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you want to query on a specific store id then you need to pass in the store id to your `retrieveData` method and use that when building the query string.

Comment: Right. But how.. do I declare the SQL statement 0 to be used for my query?